# Using TFLite file generated via Google ML Kit in TensorFlowLite Image classification example iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, firebase-mlkit

The .tflite and .txt files generated for Image classification via Google Firebase ML kit(https://developers.google.com/ml-kit) - when replaced into the Tensorflow image classification iOS sample (https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/tree/master/lite/examples/image_classification), it is identifying the images with very low accuracy and the match % is mostly below 30%.

The same .tflite and .txt files - when integrated into the Android sample code of the same Tensorflow image classification sample, it works perfectly with very high accuracy like 99%.

Any help in pointing towards a solution worth looking for would be great at this point.

I have been reading about Quantization - and Android sample has options to provide both quantized and non-quantized models (but non-quantized crashes for me for some reason). Not sure if it has anything to do with this.

If it helps, here is a link to my TFLite file generated through Google ML Kit : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WXdjGGyj2RQbSLTniQ60o0ZYb6nqlaUw/view?usp=sharing

Comment: While this is being looked into by the very supportive people at the TensorFlow organisation, we had to look for alternatives and found that the FireBase ML example works perfectly with the TFLite model files generated from Google Firebase AutoML MLKit (https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/tree/master/mlvision) on iOS platform. On Android - the TensorFlow lite Image classification example works very well but on iOS - it simply fails to match the right item. Our best guess is some compatibility issue between model generated via AutoML and TensorFlow lite.

Comment: How are you getting the models (.tflite and .txt files)?  Are you training your own model using your own images using the AutoML Vision Edge service (https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/train-image-labeler)?  If so, if you integrate such models with ML Kit's API (https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/ios/label-images-with-automl), it should work.  Is that what you r doing?  What type of images are you trying to classify?